# I'm trying to run spec/acceptance/ It gives LoadError cannot load acceptance_helper file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Error:

```
/home/geeta/DemoApp/demo_app/spec/acceptance/students_spec.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- acceptance_helper (LoadError)
    from /home/geeta/DemoApp/demo_app/spec/acceptance/students_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/geeta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `load'
    from /home/geeta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/geeta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `each'
    from /home/geeta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/geeta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
    from /home/geeta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
    from /home/geeta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /home/geeta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
    from /home/geeta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/geeta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /home/geeta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/geeta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/geeta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running command with

```
bundle exec rspec spec/...
```